# Php - Browser cache and authentification

Tags: php, authentication, caching

I have a website with filtered content, so i have cache problems : When a user with enough rights visit page with private content, the browser put the private content in cache, and when the user disconnect the private content is still visible.

I tryed to disable cache when a user is logged in (with a header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate")), but it brings too much problems, so my actual solution is to disable cache on all my pages, when a user is logged in or not.

Is there a better solution to handle the problem, like a way to delete all the browser cache for the website when a user log in or log out ?

I found something with html5 cache manifest, but it already seems to be deprecated ... And it don't works anyway.

I thought about an other solution, put a token in every url when a user is logged in, but it bother me a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a single parameter but with information about the user to the URL to generate a new URL cached.
That way when the user connect your cache manager will serve as this page, and if it has previously connected it will give him this page.

Eg `mydomain.com/privateurl.html?userid=123562`

Comment: If there is no better solutions, i will use it. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

```
header("Expires: Tue, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

Put Header of File

Comment: Well, this solution disable the cache on all my pages, it's what i currently do.

I wanted an other solution it's why i ask, i will maybe try the token one.